# Global React does not play nice with AMD React

Tags: reactjs, amd

I'm getting weird weird behaviour when rendering a component using an AMD-loaded React, when a global `React` already exists on the page.  Click events on components are getting fired when they should not be.

A look at the DOM implies that this stems from multiple React instances (one global, one AMD in my case) not being aware of each other, but this poses a problem when loading an AMD module at runtime that depends on React, into a page that also includes React.

How can I resolve this clash?

### Reproduction

I can make a component like this:

```
var ButtonComponent = React.createClass({
  onButtonClick: function(){
    alert(this.props.data + ' click event fired');
  },
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.button({onClick: this.onButtonClick}, this.props.data);
  }
});

(function(){ // create vanilla

  var ButtonList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return React.DOM.div({}, React.createElement(ButtonComponent, {data: this.props.data}));
    }
  });

  React.render(React.createElement(ButtonList, {data: 'button that was loaded by the page'}), document.getElementById('page-load-target'));

})();
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nudagukije/2/edit?js,output)

But as soon as I add another component using another instance of React then click the first button, then it calls the click event on the second loaded button:

```
// .... as above ....

(function(){ // create using amd

  require.config({
    paths: {
      'react': '//fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.2.min'
    }
  });

  window.setTimeout(function(){ 
    require(['react'], function(ReactFromAmd){ 
      ReactFromAmd.render(ReactFromAmd.createElement(ButtonComponent, {data: 'button that was loaded by AMD'}), document.getElementById('amd-load-target'));
    });
  }, 1000)

})();
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/riqotavoxa/11/edit?js,output)

If I use the existing, global version of React in this call (rather than `ReactFromAmd`, then it works as expected.  [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tunizobibe/2/edit?js,output)

Comment: jsbin is being weird with the HTML tab.  Please refresh the examples and ensure that they contain a valid HTML document.

Comment: Github issue filed here:  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in version 0.14.2:  http://jsbin.com/tesodoxape/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

The ancestor**s** (React instance) of `ButtonComponent` and the component created with `ReactFromAmd.createElement` are different, and yet they are in the same virtual DOM -- That's not allowed.

If you don't mind replacing AMD with browserify, I just figured out a way to let isolated/remotely-loaded React components co-exist nicely.

(To be continued if someone needs it)